# How to show a small hovering non pop up message in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qmessagebox

What i want to achieve is something like **toast messages** in android . I don't want a message box to be displayed to the user with an overlaying window of its own. I just want to display a small message that tells the user that some process is done. The message involves no user interaction and is only there to notify the user while he is interacting with the other GUI elements .

I have no idea how to do this in PyQt. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe QToolTip? http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtooltip.html

Comment: I want to show the message without any userinteraction with the GUI elements like hovering the mouse on a widget . I just want to show it as a notification . I dont think tool tip would help for that.

Comment: @Nateshbhat. Please try actually *reading* the documentation that was linked to: i.e. [QToolTip.showText](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtooltip.html#showText).

Comment: According to the documentation, QToolTip.showText( ) is the method that i was looking for . When i tried this :- `QtGui.QToolTip.showText(QtCore.QPoint(100, 200), "INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY", ui.submitPushButton)` it shows the tool tip at the coordinates relative to my screen , I want it to appear at the center of my windows . Couldn't find related examples in the documentation.